# Increase the clickable area of the button

Tags: android, button

I want to increase the clickable area of the button.But the image in the button should remain of same size.Also i have set image as a background not as source .How can i do that?

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"

        android:textColor="@color/title_gray"
        android:textSize="14sp"


        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: use `android:padding="20dp"` or more instead of padding left and right

Comment: @Clairvoyant but wid that how will clickable area increase?Also layout_width and layout_height is 25dp

Comment: @Clairvoyant's solution will make your button bigger overall.  If you want the button to be the same but to be able to click around it, then you can do a transparent button and place a layout with the stuff inside.

Comment: oh havent looked the layout_width and height. So what you can do is put button in a LinearLayout make layout_width or height double or triple to button and implement linearlayout setonclicklistener what u do with button

Comment: You should use `TouchDelegate` , look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make the parent layout of the button (of larger size or clickable size), and perform click event of that like -

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/backbuttonlayout"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
<Button
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"

        android:textColor="@color/title_gray"
        android:textSize="14sp"


        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, inside your activity, do like -

```
LinearLayout backbuttonlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.backbuttonlayout);
```

and perform setOnClickListener() on backbuttonlayout

Comment: this is bad for accesibility

Answer (score 9):

Use `TouchDelegate`

> Helper class to handle situations where you want a view to have a larger touch area than its actual view bounds. The view whose touch area is changed is called the delegate view. This class should be used by an ancestor of the delegate. To use a TouchDelegate, first create an instance that specifies the bounds that should be mapped to the delegate and the delegate view itself.

**Example**

```
public class LaunchActivity extends Activity {

   private Button MyButton;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);

       MyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);  //Your button ID
       View parent = findViewById(R.id.layout);        //Your Layout ID
       parent.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Rect delegateArea = new Rect();
                Button delegate = MyButton;
                delegate.getHitRect(delegateArea);
                delegateArea.top -= 600;           //Choose yourself
                delegateArea.bottom += 600;
                delegateArea.left -= 600;
                delegateArea.right += 600;

                TouchDelegate expandedArea = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea, delegate);
                // give the delegate to an ancestor of the view we're
                // delegating the
                // area to
                if (View.class.isInstance(delegate.getParent())) {
                    ((View) delegate.getParent())
                            .setTouchDelegate(expandedArea);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**I think this will help you out**

Comment: And here's a [link to the related documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#delegate).

Answer (score 4):

You can use padding. It will put the space inside the view (margin will put it outside).

For example the following code will provide a clickable area of 20dp but the background will be of 10dp.

```
<Button
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/your_background"
android:padding="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove margin, use padding around button.
2. Surround the button with a say a LinearLayout that has the padding round the button.
3. Add the same onclick to the LinearLayout as the Button.