# ImageButton increase hit area

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I'm new in Android development and I need to increase the hit area for two buttons grouped inside a `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/backButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_close_animation"
                android:onClick="closeActivity"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/sendbutton_inactive"
                android:onClick="onSendMessage"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

I want to increase the hit area for the back button in the left and for send button in the right.

I've tried by adding padding to each button but the image stretched and I don't want that... Also I've tried to use `TouchDelegate` starting with the back button

```
Rect delegateAreaBack = new Rect();
        ImageButton delegateBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        delegateBack.getHitRect(delegateAreaBack);
        delegateAreaBack.left -= 2600;
        TouchDelegate expandedAreaBack = new TouchDelegate(delegateAreaBack, delegateBack);
        if(View.class.isInstance(delegateBack.getParent()))
            ((View) delegateBack.getParent()).setTouchDelegate(expandedAreaBack);
```

but the hit area didn't increased... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backButton); 
button .post( new Runnable() {
public void run() { 
        final Rect rect = new Rect(); 
        button.getHitRect(rect); 
        rect.top -= 100;    // increase top hit area
        rect.left -= 100;   // increase left hit area
        rect.bottom += 100; // increase bottom hit area           
        rect.right += 100;  // increase right hit area
        button .setTouchDelegate( new TouchDelegate( rect , button)); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: parent is the parent of the button?

Comment: parent is the button

Comment: it's not working... Not even the old click isn't working right now :(

Answer (score 0):

Dana, it seems like you need to increase the size of the LinearLayout.

Here is how it looked like: https://image.prntscr.com/image/mG6IHwS4Tw25kb_6CY5Tqw.png

Here is how I made it look like https://image.prntscr.com/image/v8Hl0CrJQ3qwZOQoZMdvLg.png by changing the height to 200dp for experiment purposes.

So in all here is how made your XML look like:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="114dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="114dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:onClick="closeActivity"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:onClick="onSendMessage"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Afterwards, I used this simple code to experiment a bit with the problem and if you notice, the clickable area beneath the send button has increased.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageButton button1, button2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);


    View parent = findViewById(R.id.root); //Your Layout ID
    parent.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Rect delegateArea = new Rect();
            ImageButton delegate = button2;
            delegate.getHitRect(delegateArea);
            delegateArea.bottom += 260;


            TouchDelegate expandedArea = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea, delegate);
            // give the delegate to an ancestor of the view we're
            // delegating the
            // area to
            if (View.class.isInstance(delegate.getParent())) {
                ((View) delegate.getParent())
                .setTouchDelegate(expandedArea);
            }
        }
    });

}

}
```

Now if you notice on my second screenshot, I have increased the gap of the liner layout on the bottom and on the top therefore that means if you want this to work you need to increase the area of the layout around the buttons.

In all I did these changes to your code just to experiment with what works and which direction you should take to solve your problem. Hope this will help you.

Credit goes to @Strider as well from his post on [Increase the clickable area of the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594382/increase-the-clickable-area-of-the-button)